# How does a Loyal Cathar react to Undying Evil?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Loyal Cathar](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Loyal%20Cathar) states:

> When Loyal Cathar dies, return it to the battlefield transformed under
> your control at the beginning of the next end step.

[Undying Evil](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Undying%20Evil) states:

> Target creature gains undying until end of turn. (When it dies, if it
> had no +1/+1 counters on it, return it to the battlefield under its
> owner's control with a +1/+1 counter on it.)

If I cast Undying Evil on Loyal Cathar and it dies, would it come back as a Loyal Cathar with a +1/+1, come back as its transformed self, come back transformed AND with the +1/+1, or some other combination that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Fun Limited trick: Loyal Cathar + Mikaeus the Unhallowed. After the Cathar dies, he will come back as a Zombie at the beginning of the end step. Mikaeus gives the Zombie side (only) Undying. When the zombie Cathar dies, Undying will cause the card to come back to the battlefield as a Loyal Cathar with a +1/+1 counter on it. Rinse and repeat (slowly, since the Cathar's built-in resurrection is only for the end step).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would come back as Loyal Cathar with a +1/+1 counter on it.

Undying Evil's triggered ability returns Loyal Cathar to the battlefield upon dying, Loyal Cathar's triggered ability sets up a delayed triggered ability that returns the card "at the beginning of the next end step".

Loyal Cathar's normal return-to-battlefield trigger won't find the card in the graveyard when it resolves, so will fail to do anything.

> 603.7c A delayed triggered ability that refers to a particular object still affects it even if the object changes characteristics. However, if that object is no longer in the zone it’s expected to be in at the time the delayed triggered ability resolves, the ability won’t affect it. (Note that if that object left that zone and then returned, it’s a new object and thus won’t be affected. See rule 400.7.)

Comment: Aren't you allowed to stack the triggers anyway you want them? If you stack the normal trigger after the undying isn't it the other way around?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the active player has the choice to what order is used in such a case.

Comment: @Eregrith the player controlling the simultaneous effects can choose, not the active player. Otherwise yes, it can be chosen.

Comment: I want to retract my downvote, I overlooked the "at end of turn" part of the Cathar's ability. Yes you can choose the order in which way they resolve, but in any case, Undying returns the Cathar immediately, whereas the cathar's ability ability only does something at end of turn. By this time, the Cathar has long left the graveyard due to Undying and therefore can not do anything. Unless, of course, the Cathar dies again the same turn and triggers another instance of his ability. Please expand your answer accordingly and I will upvote instead of down :)

Comment: @rahzark You are, but undying returns it immediately, the Cathar ability returns it at the next end step, the end of this turn, or if it dies during the end step the end of the next turn. By the time the delayed trigger's conditions are met it was already returned to the battlefield by undying and the delayed trigger fails to resolve.